# I have an issue in opening a .php file. But it is only opening in dreamweaver with some errors. After opening it shows file is corrupted

Tags: php, file, corrupt

I am opening a .php file but when i opens it shows error. It only opens in dream weaver and shows this :

1&&$__id[1]==':'){$__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));$__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));}$__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';$__i=strlen($__rd);while($__i--){if($__rd[$__i]=='/'){$__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp)){$__ln=$__lp;break;}}}if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}}else{die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted. Ensure that you use binary mode when transferring files with FTP and disable the 'TAR smart cr/lf feature' if using WinZIP\n");}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}echo('Site error: the file **'.__FILE__.'** requires the ionCube PHP Loader '.basename($__ln).' to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the [ionCube Loader Wizard](http://www.ioncube.com/lw/) to assist with installation.');exit(199);
?>
E¿¦g /.ôûŒû–}¢×òzŒŒŸ~gøçO'®%­,Í·QhÛÓýåï$™ÑK 4·F¢ä«K˜6º0’ò{--·ÛãL+ÕfQëo¤-‰m,ý›ŠÝ5Nkƒºù×ƒ w¯±\…>t-

I did not understand this. i have to edit code in website but this is the problem. Please help me to resolve this

Comment: That looks obfuscated, has your site been hacked?

Comment: It's an ionCube file in the less common binary format. Not helping is that Dreamweaver must be parsing the file as HTML, and is being confused by the PHP open tag (you'd see the same were you to open the file in a browser). As it is protected you can't edit the file. As an aside, I would recommend using a competent text editor such as Sublime over Dreamweaver.